# Use Tensorboard With Tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow.js

I would like to use [`tensorboard`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard) to visualize my model fitting.

The instructions for the [tensorboard tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) (which is for python)  and in the [API docs (JS)](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_node/1.1.0/) use `tf.node`.

But `tf.node` does not exist.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'summaryFileWriter' of undefined
```

My code:

```
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
console.clear();
require('dotenv').config();
const debugTf = require('debug')('tf');
const debugTfVerbose = require('debug')('tf:verbose');
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const summaryWriter = tf.node.summaryFileWriter('/tmp/tfjs_tb_logdir');
```

I'm using `"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.2.3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_node/1.1.0/), the namespace `tf` should be associated to the package `tfjs-node` instead of `tf`

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
```

Comment: I always thought the one `require` is to load the engine e.g. gpu or cpu and the other one is for the library. Was already wondering why I land on to diff. documentations from google. Thx